# Unlocking account web3.js 1.0 on AWS Lambda

Tags: web3js, aws, web3js-v1.x

I'm getting following error message when trying to unlock account on AWS Lambda:

```
Error: Node error: {"code":-32601,"message":"The method personal_unlockAccount does not exist/is not available"}
    at Function.validate (/var/task/node_modules/web3-providers/dist/web3-providers.cjs.js:111:18)
    at HttpProvider._callee$ (/var/task/node_modules/web3-providers/dist/web3-providers.cjs.js:674:61)
    at tryCatch (/var/task/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/var/task/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:22)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/var/task/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/var/task/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
    at _next (/var/task/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:25:9)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
```

```js
'use strict';

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'ap-northeast-1'});
const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

const Web3 = require('web3');  
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(process.env['INFURA_ENDPOINT']));
const abiSource = require('./lib/myToken.json');
const abi = abiSource.abi;
const contractAddress = process.env['CONTRACT_ADDRESS'];
const myToken = web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);

.
.
.

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  event = event.body || event;
  const senderAddress = event.sender_address;
  const privateKey = event.private_key;
  try{
    await web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(senderAddress, privateKey, 600);
  }catch(error){
    console.log(error);
    return getResponse(200, 'Internal server error');
  }

  .
  .
  .
};
```

My contract is deployed on Ropsten network, 
Although I have some code for processing transaction in following, which raises same error.
Any ideas how to fix that / what the cause of error is?

Node version: 8.0 Web3: 1.0.0-beta50

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Node version: 8.0` is a very insufficient piece of information. What type of node is this (e.g., Parity, Geth, etc)?

Comment: In any case, you probably forgot to enable the `personal` API when you started that node. For example, in Parity, see `--jsonrpc-apis` or `--ws-apis` or `--ipc-apis` (choose the one corresponding to your connection type, most likely the first one I suppose).

Comment: I also recommend that you use `web3.js v1.0.0-beta34` (or at most 37). There have been various issues in later versions AFAIK.

Comment: I mean `Node.js 8.x` as AWS Lambda execution environment, and `Infura.io` for Ethereum client. For now I've downgraded to `v1.0.0-beta34`, but the consequence remain same. Let me look it up 2nd comment and figure it out, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install a web3 layer for your lambda. See https://github.com/scenarex/web3-lambda-layer for how to do so.